# Firestore request domain specific security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Is there any way to check and accept only specific domains that can access the firestore in security rules? My app doesn't have any authentication, so I don't have any other way to secure the firestore.

Comment: It's not possible, domain of origin is easily spoofed - there is no real security in that.

Comment: Then is it possible to get rid of the "your firestore security rules are insecure" email? That's all I'm trying to do, but I don't have any other way to secure it

Comment: Without seeing what you have now, we don't know what the problem is that it's complaining about.